# saving highscore into sqlite

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, flash-cs6

i was trying to make highscore for my game. but as i was trying to save the highscore on the table database on sqlite i have some error saying 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at DDRnew_fla::MainTimeline/ext()[DDRnew_fla.MainTimeline::frame26:64]
my actionscript is like this

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.events.SQLEvent;
import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var fileDB:File;
var koneksi:SQLConnection;
var sqlStatement:SQLStatement;
perfectcount.text = "" + int(perfect);
greatcount.text = "" + int(great);
goodcount.text = "" + int(good);
boocount.text = "" + int(boo);
misscount.text = "" + int(miss);
scorecount.text = "" + int(score);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ranking);
exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ext);

init();

function init()
{
    koneksi = new SQLConnection();
    koneksi.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, koneksiHandler);
    koneksi.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
    fileDB = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath);
    fileDB = fileDB.resolvePath("DDR.db");
    koneksi.open(fileDB);
}

function koneksiHandler(e:SQLEvent)
{
    sqlStatement = new SQLStatement();
    sqlStatement.sqlConnection = koneksi;
    sqlStatement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
}


function ranking(event:Event):void
{
if (score>=846000)
{
    rank.text = "A";
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ranking);
}
else if (score>=658000)
{
    rank.text = "B";
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ranking);
}
else if (score>=470000)
{
    rank.text = "C";
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ranking);
}
else if (score>=282000)
{
    rank.text = "D";
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ranking);
}
else
{
    rank.text = "E";
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ranking);
}

}
function ext(e:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop("main menu");
var scoretxt:String ="" + int(score);
var ranktxt:String = rank.text;
var queryString:String;
queryString = "INSERT INTO easy1 (score, Rank) VALUES ('" + scoretxt + "', '" + ranktxt + "')";
var sqlQuery:String = queryString;
sqlStatement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, querySukses);
sqlStatement.text = sqlQuery;
sqlStatement.execute();
}
function querySukses(e:SQLEvent)
{
sqlStatement.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, querySukses);
e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ext);

}
function errorHandler(e:*):void
{
trace("Eksekusi statement error.");
}
```

line 64 is the var ranktxt:String = rank.text; and perfect, great, good, boo, miss is variable for scoring. i need a solution for this thnx before

Comment: i guess `rank` is a textfield on stage? Make sure the textfield exists on the frame you are executing that code.

Comment: yes it is a textfield and already exist

Comment: 0 answers. That's why you should not write your code in frames

Comment: if i'm not suppose to write my code in frame where should i write it ? notepad ?. btw it solved already just need to write var ranktxt:string before gotoandstop

Comment: Not in notepad but in separated classes

Comment: hahaha okay i'll try studying about class later ^^

Comment: you can still write it in notepad if you like :P